# Simple javascript PHP default variable issue

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I don't know why I can't figure out a way to do this... This is basic programming logic. For some reason, my mind is just not working right today though. I have a page that loads and runs some javascript. When the page firsdt loads, the javascript needs to run using a default variable, however when a user clicks a link on the page, a PHP variable is set which gets sent to the javascript side of things changing the outcome of the javascript if statement. For some reason though, I just cant figure out how to get this to work. Please help.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Change the username
    var phpusername = "<?php echo $username; ?>";
    if(phpusername == (undefined || null)) {
        (This is where the default condition code will go)
    } else {
        (This is where code will run when user updates username)
    }
</script>
```

There is a little more to this story as to why I am doing things this way (Using both PHP and Javascript), so please resist offering radically different solutions. There is a LOT more to this puzzle not shown here, however the rest of the puzzle does not necessarily effect the functionality of this part.

Thanks!

Comment: `phpusername` can never be `undefined` or `null` because you’ve wrapped it in `""` quotes, meaning it will always be a string, failing the equivalence test.

Comment: @Xufox Any suggestions?

Comment: @Xufox please post that as an answer for Atomiklan.  Atomiklan, I reckon that you set a fallback/default empty value for $_POST in the php part and then check that in the js.  But Xufox spotted it first, (s)he should post that as an answer to get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';  // set fallback value
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Change the username
    var phpusername = '<?php echo $username; ?>';
    if(phpusername == '') {                              // check if empty
        (This is where the default condition code will go)
    } else {
        (This is where code will run when user updates username)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It’s alright. I wasn’t sure what the default value would be. The empty string is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Works great now!